# How can I specify network interface for redis replication?

Tags: redis, replication

I'm using Redis 3.2.0 and enabled replication. But I got result for "info replication" as follows:

> master_link_status:down

Redis log shows:

> Connecting to MASTER master_host:6379
>
> MASTER <-> SLAVE sync started
>
> ...
>
> Timeout connecting to the MASTER
>
> Connecting to MASTER master_host:6379
>
> ...

Ping and telnet to port 6379 of master host from slave host is succeeded.

So, I thought redis process on slave host is trying to connect to master host via wrong network interface(slave host has multiple network interfaces).

Can I specify network interface which is used by redis replication?

Answer (score 1):

When Redis connects to master host, client socket is binded to address which is specified by first argument of "bind" parameter.